# Blazor INPUT control e.Key Undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, blazor

I'm trying to intercept the characters typed in an input control, the following code works well:

```
<input id="txtInput" type="text" @onkeypress="KeyHandler" @onkeypress:preventDefault @bind="@InputContent" @bind:event="oninput" />

private void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)            
{
    string sPattern = "abcd@";      
    if (sPattern.Contains(e.Key))
    {
        InputContent += e.Key;
    }
}
```

but... when typing '@' e.Key the result is 'undefined'

this probably also happens in other cases, I would like to avoid using javascript. Why is this happening? where is the error

Comment: Your code produces no such error...Are you using the latest versions? The is no reason why '@' will produce such an error.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine. I don't think you have any issue in your code.

```
    @page "/counter"

    <input @bind="currentCount" @onkeydown="KeyDownHandler" />
    <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

    @code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
    protected void KeyDownHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Key pressed: {e.Key} | Code: {e.Code}");
    }
 }
```

This prints what you type including special characters. Thanks

Comment: yes but, when I type on my keyboard Alt Gr + @ (the key with ç ò and @) e.key debug value is 'Control' and then the rest of the combination, this doesn't happen in javascript, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Renzo however i'm not sure how to type ò or any character like this thru my keyboard, but when i paste them into input box, i get following keycode and keypressed.
INPUT : ò
OUTPUT : Key pressed: Control | Code: ControlLeft
                  Key pressed: v | Code: KeyV

Comment: i think javascrpt would be needed, the key combinations don't work, amen